# Python - module has not attribute

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am in the process of splitting my long single python script into multiple files/modules. In the process of doing so, I have hit the following issue. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong syntax wise or just the basic logic is wrong.

My current folder structure is as follows

```
parentFolder
    folA
        __init__.py
        fileA.py
        fileB.py
    app.py
```

fileB.py

```
def test():
    print("Hello from fileB")
```

fileA.py

```
import fileB
def run():
    fileB.test()
    print("Hello from fileA")
```

app.py

```
from folA import fileA
fileA.run()
```

I get the error "AttributeError: module 'fileB' has no attribute 'test'.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to do `from fileB import test`, then just run `test()`

Comment: I realize I can do that in app.py but I was hoping that I can use fileB in fileA and then just call the parent function in app.py. Use it as building blocks and then just build on top rather than calling it separately.

Comment: No, I mean in fileA, you can do that. Otherwise, in app, it would need to be `from folA import fileB`

Comment: Ah okay I tried that as well, if I do that in fileA then I get the "ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'fileB'"

Comment: Have you *saved* `fileB.py`?

Comment: Yes, saved the file.

Comment: Is this python 2? I don't think the imports as shown in your code should work in python 3; you'd have to replace `import fileB` with `from . import fileB`.

Comment: Can you add `print(fileB.__file__)` to `fileA.py` and confirm that the path of the `fileB` module is as expected? Maybe you're importing a different file by accident.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it, I am using python 3.  I changed it and it now works, thanks!

Comment: Cool. Note: Always tag your Python version on the quesiton

Comment: Yes, apologies. Didn't realize this much had changed since python 2. Still catching up on the changes.

Comment: Tags aren't intended to indicate which python version the OP is using :/ They're only supposed to be used if the question is specifically related to that version of python.